# Obtener solo letras de una cadena con expresiones regulares C#

Tags: c#, regex

Hola estoy haciendo una app que usa folio inicial e inicial, estoy usando expresiones regulares para obtener solo el numero, en este caso si funciona con @"(\d+)".
fInicial = 00001
fFinal = 00005

```
string fInicial = Regex.Match(txtBoxInicial.Text, @"(\d+)").Value;  //TXT00001  
string fFinal = Regex.Match(txtBoxFinal.Text, @"(\d+)").Value; //TXT00005
```

Pero quiero obtener letras osea "TXT".
Espero darme a enteder y agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Eso no es algo como `\w+`?

Comment: Si usas ese patrón cualquier carácter alfanumérico va coincidir.
Por aquí les dejo la documentación oficial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Comment: Tu pregunta se puede interpretar de muchas formas diferentes. ¿Podrás [edit] agregando algunos ejemplos con sus resultados esperados?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener solo letras de una cadena de texto usa el siguiente patrón:
`[a-zA-Z ]`